# Is work done against or, with the field?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, work

Imagine you have a circuit with charged conductors. Electrons goes from this first conductor, to a second one. We would like to find out the charge of this first conductor. Using common sense, if electrons are repelled from this first conductors, the charge shall be negative, no?

$$
\mathbf E = - \nabla \phi
$$
The minus sign ensures that the $\mathbf E$ goes against the increase of the potential.
$$
\Delta \phi = -\int_{r_0}^{r_1} \mathbf E \cdot d \mathbf r
$$

Now this is the  work  done against the $\mathbf E$ field, no? (The minus
sign again, ensures this).

$$
\mathbf E = -\nabla  \phi \\
\Delta \phi = -\int_{r_0}^{r_1} \mathbf E \cdot d \mathbf r \Rightarrow \\
\Delta \phi = \int_{r_0}^{r_1} \nabla \phi \cdot d \mathbf r 
$$
By the fundamental theorem of vector calculus:
$$
\int_{\mathbf r}^{\mathbf r'} \nabla V \cdot d \mathbf r =
V(\mathbf r') -  V(\mathbf r)
$$
Now this shall be the work done agains the $\mathbf E$ field. Now let's  reason a little bit.

The electron is near the first conductor (suppose that is negatively charged) and it moves following the $\mathbf E$ field; then the following applies:
$$
\phi(\mathbf r') - \phi(\mathbf r) > 0
$$
Which is positive!?! This result is against everything that I said before. Negative work should be work against the field, and positive, with  the field, no?

Could someone make this clearer to me? I would I apreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

An electron moves against field lines,  as the electron moves against the field lines, There is a net positive change in potential. Electrons move through positive potential gradients.

The relation between potential difference and the work done per unit charge is that they are negatives of eachother, this means as the electron moves, there is negative work done per unit charge.

multiplied by the negative charge of the electron means that the work done is positive.

Your confusion lies in the "Per unit charge" aspect of the definition between the relationship between potential and work done per unit charge

Comment: So... $\phi(\mathbf r') - \phi(\mathbf r)$ is work done per unit charge. In this case is positive. For  obtaining the work, I just have to multiply this by the charge: $W = e \Delta 
 V$, and now is negative, that was the thing I was expecting. You mean that, no?

Comment: The relationship for a conservative  electric force is $\Delta W = -q \Delta V$ For an electron moving against field lines $\Delta V$ is positive, so the work done per unit charge js negative, times by a negative q means positive work is done.